# Weird Spaces Between <tr><td> Only on iOS and Android

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've prepared signature for outlook app and everythings works good on web clients like gmail and also in outlook app.
But the problem is when I am testing signature on iOS and Android.

This is code snippet to show my concept.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta media="screen" type="text/css">
</head>
<style>
     tr{padding:0px !Important; margin:0px !important;}
</style>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="min-width: 100%; font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;">

<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="139"><span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #000; text-align:left;">Test</span><br />
      <br />
      <span style="font-size: 13pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #3580C2; text-align:left;">Test2</span><br />
      <span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; color: #000; text-align:left;">Test3</span><br /></td>
    <td width="211">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="test.png" width="139" height="209" alt="zdjecie" style="vertical-align: middle; display: block;" /></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left: 10px; border-collapse: collapse;" >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>
            <table style="margin-left: 15px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><img alt="phone" src="/image006.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: block;" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp; 000 000 000 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img alt="fax" src="/image008.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: block;" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp; 000 000 000 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img alt="cell" src="/image010.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: block;" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp; 000 000 000 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img alt="mail" src="/image012.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: block;" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp; name@web.com </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px;"><br />
            <br />
            <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;"><b>Company name</b></span><br />
            <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;">address</span><br />
            <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;">00000000000</span><br />
            <a style="color:black; text-decoration:none; display: block;" href="http://www.web.com"> <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;"><b>www.web.com</b></span></a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 8pt; width: 760px; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <br>
                    <img src="/image013.png" style="width: 274px; height: 35px; display: block;" />
               </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td style="padding-left:0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">
                    <p> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>

                    <p> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test.</p>

                    <p> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
               </td>
          </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This shows problem on iOS

[image: screen]

Comment: unfortunately not all "default" values are the same among all browsers... Normalize CSS might a bottom ground where to start: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ - EDIT: Oh it's about mail template... Well it could help either way...

Comment: This might also be helpful https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/reset-styles/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/reset-styles/ -

```
table, td{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

might be the style that you are looking for.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put reset-rules into the initial table and then any nested tables before applying normal-rules on the td elements. I have used this approach successfully in the past on cross-platform email signatures.

I've also come across research that says many email clients tend to ignore `!important`; either totally or in specific parts of the HTML structure. Margin is another property that is almost universally ignored.

Some people are in favour of using empty `td` elements just to enforce padding.